# Setting Active Directory Account Expiration with LDAP and C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am wanting to set a new users account to expire in 90 days from when it is created. Here is my code to create the user and set everything up. Everything works except for the last block where i am trying to set it to expire.

```
            DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + cnUser, "user");
            newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = cnUser;
            newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = cnUser;
            newUser.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            //Changes Password
            String passwrd = userPassword.ToString();
            newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { passwrd });
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            //Sets User Account to Change Passowrd on new login
            newUser.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            //Enables account
            newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = (int)newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value & ~0x2;
            newUser.CommitChanges();

            //Set the account to expire in 90 days
            var dt1 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(90);
            newUser.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = dt1.ToFileTime().ToString();
            newUser.CommitChanges();
```

Any Suggestions on how to get his working?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [The Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx) about this field. You'll need to convert that to "ticks" --

```
the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). A value of 0 or 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (9223372036854775807) indicates that the account never expires.
```

`new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(90).Ticks - new DateTime(1601, 1, 1).Ticks)` will get you the correct and exact value.

You can check your work (manually) by getting the value from the above expression and executing:

```
w32tm.exe /ntte 130149277684873234
```

The results of the above command for me was

```
150635 17:42:48.4873234 - 6/5/2013 12:42:48 PM
```

Comment: DateTime's Ticks counts ticks from 1st Jan 0001. It needs to be normalized to count ticks starting at 1st Jan 1601.

Comment: The DateTime.Today.Add(90).Ticks give the correct date as far as month and day but for the year it has it set to 3613, basically adding in the 1600 from where the ticks begin.

Comment: OK, so subtracting `new DateTime(1600, 1, 1).Ticks` should fix it.  Updated answer coming soon

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. `var dt1 =DateTime.Today.AddDays(90).Ticks - new DateTime(1601, 1, 1).Ticks;`

Answer (score 7):

Or you could do:

```
DateTime expire = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
newUser.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = Convert.ToString((Int64)expire.ToFileTime());
newUser.CommitChanges();
```

This is a bit easier to deal with than messing with ticks and all that

Comment: Cool! right to the point!

Answer (score 0):

reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180914(v=vs.80).aspx

```
//Use the DirectoryEntry.InvokeSet method to invoke the AccountExpirationDate property setter.

System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry dirEntryLocalMachine =
    new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + "/" + userID);

dirEntryLocalMachine .InvokeSet("AccountExpirationDate", new object[] {new DateTime(2005, 12, 29)});

//Commit the changes.
usr.CommitChanges();
```